# Hyperlink in Page with current site URL

Tags: 2010, url, hyperlink

I work with site templates. On this site templates are hyperlinks to some views from list or libraries. 
I'm working with something like this as hyperlink http//abc/def/ghi.aspx
Currently i have to change every hyperlink when i add a new site with my templates. Is it possible to add the hyplerink in another way to get the current site URL?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what do you mean with "Site patterns"? Some PowerShell script or a WebTemplate with modules?

Comment: Sorry i meant template. Wrong vocabulary...i edited my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are the links included? If they are in a web part page, you can put them as relative links in an HTML form web part. This way the links will not be 'recalculated' by sharepoint into hard-coded ones, which usually happens if you just use CEWP. Links in the quick launch are never relative, at least from my experience.

Comment: The links are included in a web part page with a CEWP. I'll add the links with a HTML form web part and hope that works

Comment: Perfect, it worked with the HTML form web part